# Which book would you like to see "texified"?

Tags: soft-question, big-list, books

Let's see if we could use MO to put some pressure on certain publishers...

Although it is wonderful that it has been put 
[online](http://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/DMOS.pdf), I think it would make an even greater read if "Hodge Cycles, Motives and Shimura Varieties" by Deligne, Milne, Ogus and Shih would be (re)written in the latex typesetting (well, if I could understand its content..).

But enough about my opinion, what do you think? Which book(s) would you like to see "texified"? As customary in a CW question, one book per answer please.

Comment: Speak of the devil! A texified copy of the second article from DMOS has just appeared on Milne's website (under Expository Notes). The first is already there (under Documents).

Comment: @mehpisto what a coincidence! Thank you for pointing it out :)

Comment: Is this an idle question, or will anon deliver?

Comment: @darij I was hoping the publishers of the books mentioned in the answers could deliver! I think this question needs more upvotes if we want to make a strong case though...

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this question.  What is it supposed to mean?  Your favorite older math books?  I can't imagine how it would be useful to anyone.

Comment: @Andy the idea to ask this question came to me a while after I viewed the website http://outofprintmath.blogspot.com/ . I thought that maybe it could be of use as a means of negotiating with publishers, in the sense that people could say "Please mister [head of publisher X], publish the book [Y] in TEX typesetting, it would be much more readable if you did." Then the head of publisher X would say: "Hm... you've got a point, but I am not going to do this solely for you!" Then you say: "Well, a lot of people agree with me, just take a look at this MO question." (You show him/her this question.) 

Comment: S/he strokes his/her beard and mumbles: "Hmmm... a lot of people seem to agree with you, perhaps we can make some profit out of this. I will take your suggestion into consideration. By the way, that website of yours looks pretty good, perhaps I'll join it too."

Comment: @Max : I am pretty dubious that a MO post will have any effect on a publisher.

Comment: While I don't want to sound discouraging. It would seem a lot
more useful to contact the author, as a first step.

Comment: @Andy & Donu: Ok perhaps you're both right. I have to admit I didn't think my question through that thoroughly.

Comment: I have some sympathy with Max's question. While I don't have any data to argue against Andy's assessment of the (lack of) impact of this MO post on publishers, I think some publishers may be amenable to TeX versions being produced. Disclaimer: I have a private TeXed version of Mem AMS 127 (1972) and at one point had an email from the AMS saying they had no problem with me making my copy available on a personal basis for personal use. Doubt they'll ever officially sanction it, or use it to republish, though...

Comment: See also the TAC reprints http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/index.html - not exactly the same as what Max was asking, but evidence that the appetite sometimes exists for such TeX-ifying projects

Comment: My impression is that things are _much_ more complicated than this. For example the LMS just reprinted Cassels-Froehlich and they had to try to get official permission from all the people who wrote all the articles first, and then some of them were dead etc etc. I think it all took a long time. Someone mentions EGA/SGA below but Grothendieck will not give his permission to reprint and actually explicitly asked people who were TeXifying bits of SGA to stop. I am almost certain that MO has epsilon role to play here. You need to talk direct to publishers and authors.

Comment: I'm on the negative side for keeping this question, since it's too fuzzy and open-ended.   Who owns published material is often a complicated issue.   (I was actually contacted recently by a European Springer editor about who was next-of-kin to one of my deceased older brothers, who had edited his deceased thesis advisor's last book, which a former publisher had issued but which Springer wanted to reprint.)

Comment: @Jim: !!! ${}{}$

Comment: Why go to the publishers? Why not round up five to ten people, agree on a common latex style, type the book up yourselves then put the source and result on a website somewhere? It may demand a lot of work and be illegal as hell, but copyright laws in science are morally wrong anyway.

Comment: on the technical side, I have texified some legacy material using OCR software from the Infty Project, with good results. Of course, proof reading is still required, but it does interpret most of the math correctly.

http://www.inftyproject.org

Comment: While it is not the type of question which can have a good canonical answer but is rather a discussion topic, it is not for MathOverflow. However, people who closed it should suggest the place online to continue this discussion. You can not just close something what has tens of comments without channeling it somewhere..

Comment: @Zoran and all: A good place to move this type of discussion to is the collection of blogs indexed by http://www.mathblogging.org/planetmo .

Answer (score 29):

EGA, with hyperlinks for easy navigation.

Comment: Hyperlinks are indeed very useful; it would be even better if it was easy way to go back to the page you were just reading.

Comment: @André Most modern PDF-viewers come with a "back in the document" button that does what you are asking for; e.g., acrobat reader, okular, skim etc.

Comment: @Peter Really? Where? I've never seen it in acrobat (and would be happy to be poited to it)

Comment: @Peter McNamara: I think Adobe Reader does not show back/forward buttons as default and I don't use it myself. Try editing the toolbar and look for back/forward buttons. Also, try alt+right, alt+left (on windows) or whatever combination your browser uses to navigate. And if all fails, google.

Comment: @Peter McNamara: Reader is not really ideal. I have been using Foxit for some time and it is much faster, has back/forward buttons, lets you make bookmarks, etc. 

Comment: Acrobat does have a "previous view", but you have to right-click to see it :)

Comment: https://ega.fppf.site/ ;-)

Answer (score 18):

Milnor - Lectures on the h-cobordism theorem

Comment: Everything by Milnor.

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: Me too. Especially *Morse Theory*.

Comment: To be honest, I would definitely prefer the typewriter version of Morse Theory than the Texified version. This book is one of the few math book in typewritter style that managed to present readable (and in my opinion, even beautiful) math formulae.

Answer (score 16):

Atiyah - K-Theory

Comment: I agree.  Improve the index as well.


Comment: I have LaTeXed form Chapter I through Appendix. Anyone interested?

Answer (score 14):

All the SGA's. Note that SGA 1 and 2 already exists in TeX, and there is something for SGA 3 and 4.

Comment: I'll add that I just finished typesetting SGA 4.5 (on etale cohomology). It can be found at http://www.math.cornell.edu/~dkmiller/bin/sga4.5.pdf

Answer (score 12):

Rolfsen - Knots and Links

Answer (score 9):

Atiyah + Macdonald, *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*.

Comment: The AW typesetting if this book is pretty good already, isn't it?

Comment: You haven't seen a paperback version of this. The printing, at least, is awful.

Comment: @Simon, you're right, I haven't seen a paperback version.

Answer (score 8):

Marcus - Number Fields

Comment: That's my favorite candidate for real typesetting for two reasons: the book is great and the typewritten text is awful to look at. And it was so at the time the book came out.

Comment: A LaTeXed version was published din 2018 by Springer.

Answer (score 8):

Chern - Complex manifolds without potential theory

Answer (score 6):

Leon Simon - Lectures on Geometric Measure Theory

Answer (score 5):

"Lectures on Chevalley Groups" - by Robert Steinberg

Comment: A thorough search on the web will lead you to a TeXed/PDFed version of this.

Comment: Can you give a link? I can't find it.

Comment: @Emmanuel Kowalski: I would appreciate that as well, I've been looking forever by now.

Comment: Strangely I can't locate it any more either... The title page of the file claims the TeXing was done by C. Drupieski, but it does not seem to be on his home page... However there is the following PDF scan of the original(A. Ram says he got permission from Steinberg to make it available): http://www.math.wisc.edu/%7Eram/YaleNotes.pdf


Comment: I have now posted a copy of my LaTeX version from 2007 on my web page. It appears that some other folks also produced a LaTeX version in 2013. https://sites.google.com/site/chevalleygroups/notes

Answer (score 4):

Palais - Foundations of global non–linear analysis

Answer (score 4):

Adams - Lectures on Lie Groups

Answer (score 2):

Stong - Notes on cobordism theory

Answer (score 1):

Paul Cohen - *Set Theory and the Continuum Hypothesis*.

Answer (score 1):

Robin Hartshorne's lecture notes on projective geometry.  This appeared as a book and is now out of print.  The pages appear to be photographs of pages produced with a typewriter, plus hand-drawn illustrations.

Maybe a wiki should be set up where volunteers can transcribe from the book.  Permission from copyright owners might be easy to get if they're not interested in continuing to publish it themselves, and if they are, an attempt to get permission for such a wiki might pressure them to put it back in print with better typesetting.

Comment: LaTeXed at http://www.math.rug.nl/~piter/KR/Hartshorne.pdf - I'm not sure if legally or not.

Answer (score 1):

"Rational Homotopy Theory and Differential Forms." by Griffiths and Morgan.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Reed. *Abstract Non Linear Wave Equations*.