# Correction to Milnor's h-cobordism book

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, cobordism

> This is a cross-post from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3354893/272127).

These four screenshots from milnor's book baffled me a bit (pages 24, 50, 51 and i-iii resp.):

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

> 1. In first one, there is no Theorem 3.1 in the book, but there is def 3.1.
> 2. In second screenshot, is $-x_\lambda$ redundant? (although the expression is correct in this case).
> 3. The other one stand for $-x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n)$ or $-x_2,\dots,-x_n)$ or $x_2,\dots,x_n)$?
> 4. in the Introduction page (last screenshot) there are some cross-references such as $\S 7.6$, $\S 2.1$ .... But there is no sections like these. Maybe his purpose is Theorem 7.6 or Theorem 2.1?

Sorry for such question. I need these correction because of [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/318915/90655).

Comment: For those who want to look at the book and do not have one. http://93.174.95.29/_ads/A7DB90A54CD85C125A9BF3FC4E1BA855

Comment: When you read the book you’ll be able to find out which theorem/section Milnor is referencing for 1 and 4. As for 2 I don’t understand your quibble, just because you think it’s redundant doesn’t mean Milnor made a mistake (he didn’t). As for 3, the notation was already clarified in the lines above, plus he wrote “critical points of same index \lambda” which tells you where the minus signs are.