# Where to upload digitized LaTeX versions of old papers?

Tags: soft-question, online-resources, latex, bibliography

Let's say I took the time to convert into proper modern LaTeX a few old math papers (which cannot be found online, or only in poorly scanned versions which are hard to read due to this). If someone else happened to want to read them, I would be happy to spare them some time by sharing my versions. **Where would you upload such files?**

Note that the case I am considering here is merely a one-to-one LaTeX transcription of the original papers, without any improvement to the text or the math (say, except some typos fixed maybe). In particular, I do not have and do not want to claim any type of ownership on this content.

Comment: Have you considered posting them on the arXiv?

Comment: The arxiv has papers of Euler translated to English and uploaded, so I agree with Leo Alonso. See https://arxiv.org/search/?query=Euler_L&searchtype=author&source=header

Comment: I had considered posting on the arXiv, but I am unsure how such a submission would comply with their "third party submission" policy : https://arxiv.org/help/third_party_submission

Comment: Contact arxiv to explain your submissions, as it says on that third party submission webpage.

Comment: I have seen translations on arXiv, but not one-to-one transcriptions.

Comment: Not quite the same, but I transcribed a letter of Tate's and posted it on the ArXiv, where the author is listed as John Tate and I'm listed in the "submitted by" field. Of course, I asked Tate's permission before doing so. So one question is "how old are the papers"? If they're still in copyright, that's potentially an issue. If the author(s) are still alive, you might ask their permission. Here's the paper that I posted: https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.5765

Comment: In https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.05198 there is a translation of the classical paper of Siegel about Riemann's nachlass, where he consider the Riemann-Siegel expansion.  As authors appear as the translators, which I did not consider good, because it is difficult to find by search on the web.

Comment: I want to emphasize what others have said: if the authors are alive, the first step is to contact them.  If they are dead, but fairly recently (say, 10-20 years), it’s a little more complicated since there might e.g. be family or close collaborators who should be consulted (and figuring out who that is is more complicated that just googling).

Comment: Related: [Old books you would like to have reprinted with high-quality typesetting](https://mathoverflow.net/q/318839)